# Rendering pairs in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to render resultset from API in pairs (if it is odd number I am removing oldest one).

I have no idea how to do it with map function (firstly as if total returned is odd number I am removing one)

This code is working for me (sort off), but I need to put "Block" tag inside, and then it is braking for me...

this is code that it supposed to be like... but it is not working for me ( I am getting syntax error "Unterminated regular expression...") :

```
var startingTag = true;
var renderedProducts = [];
for (let i = 0; i < newPairsSize; i++) {
    if (startingTag) {
        renderedProducts.push(
            <Block flex row><Product
                key={i}
                product={smallPosts[i]}
                style={{ marginRight: theme.SIZES.BASE }}
            />
        );
        startingTag = false;
    } else {
        renderedProducts.push(<Product key={i} product={smallPosts[i]} /></Block>);
        startingTag = true;
    }
}
```

If I remove "Block" tag it is not throwing errors for me, but I need that tag in there:

```
var startingTag = true;
var renderedProducts = [];
for (let i = 0; i < newPairsSize; i++) {
    if (startingTag) {
        renderedProducts.push(
            <Product
                key={i}
                product={smallPosts[i]}
                style={{ marginRight: theme.SIZES.BASE }}
            />
        );
        startingTag = false;
    } else {
        renderedProducts.push(<Product key={i} product={smallPosts[i]} />);
        startingTag = true;
    }
}
```

And finally I am putting sample of the static code... this how it is supposed to look like

```
<Block flex>
    <Block flex row>
        <Product
            product={suggestions[0]}
            style={{ marginRight: theme.SIZES.BASE }}
        />
        <Product product={suggestions[1]} />
    </Block>
    <Block flex row>
        <Product
            product={suggestions[2]}
            style={{ marginRight: theme.SIZES.BASE }}
        />
        <Product product={suggestions[3]} />
    </Block>
</Block>
```

Does anyone have any suggestion (PS. I tried putting it in variable.. concatenating it... nothing..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody ever need something like this....

this might do the trick:

```
var renderedProducts = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < newPairsSize; i += 2) {
                renderedProducts.push(
                    <Block key={i} flex row>
                        <Product
                            product={smallPosts[i]}
                            style={{ marginRight: theme.SIZES.BASE }}
                        />
                        <Product product={smallPosts[i + 1]} />
                    </Block>
                );
            }
```